# <name> expected near 'end' error

Tags: lua

when I ran my lua code I got the error 'name' expected near 'end' | Line 12

Here's the code:

```
local i = 1
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer


function start()
repeat
    wait()
    game.ReplicatedStorage.addpoints:FireServer()
until i == 2
end

function end()
i = 2
end

plr.Chatted:connect(function(message)
if message == "start" then
    start()
elseif message == "end" then
    end()
end
end)
```

Any fix?

Comment: `end` higlighted..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function end()
  i = 2
end
```

Here, `end` is a keyword, you can't use it as a function name. How about `stop`?